# pascalprecht.translate how translate message with parameter?

Tags: angularjs, translate

I have a piece of code and I would like to switch to "ON" and "OFF" were also translated, but how to do it?

```
<label class="toggle modal-label-box">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-toggle2" ng-model="faculty" value="7">
    <i data-swchon-text="ON" data-swchoff-text="OFF"></i><span translate>SOME</span>
</label>
```

if anyone would have any idea about this please share,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class="toggle modal-label-box">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-toggle2" ng-model="faculty" value="7">
    <i data-swchon-text="ON" data-swchoff-text="OFF"></i>
</label>
```

it might otherwise, as you can instead of:

```
data-swchon-text = "ON" data-swchoff-text = "OFF"
```

to use:
`data-swchon-text = "{{swich.on}}" and data-swchoff-text = "{{swich.off}}"` ?

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<i ng-switch-on="{{ ON }}" ng-switch-off="{{ OFF }}"></i>
```

js:

```
app.directive('ngSwitchOn', function() {
    return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('ngSwitchOn', function(data) {
            elem.attr('data-swchon-text', data);
        });
    };
});

app.directive('ngSwitchOff', function() {
    return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('ngSwitchOff', function(data) {
            elem.attr('data-swchoff-text', data);
        });
    };
});
```